# Using axios with reactjs to call asp.net api localhost

Tags: react-native, asp.net-web-api, axios

I've spent for many hours. I decide to post the question.

I have an API that is developed by asp.net on a solution.

```
public class ApiOpsController : ApiController
    {
        private static readonly IOpsRepository OpsRepository = new OpsRepository();

        public IEnumerable<Opdt> Get(string styleCode, string styleSize, string styleColor, string revNo, string opRevNo,
            string edition, string languageId)
        {
            return OpsRepository.Get(styleCode, styleSize, styleColor, revNo, opRevNo, edition, languageId);
        }
    }
```

I run the solution then use postman to test the API

http://localhost:63762/api/ApiOps?styleCode=UAR0348&styleSize=RGL&styleColor=001&revNo=002&opRevNo=001&edition=MES&languageId=en

[image]

Of course, it works as well.

I call the API on my Reactjs project

```
  const config = {
    method: "get",
    url: "http://localhost:63762/api/ApiOps?styleCode=UAR0348&styleSize=RGL&styleColor=001&revNo=002&opRevNo=001&edition=MES&languageId=en",   
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }
  };

  let res = await axios(config).catch(error => console.log(error));;
```

It throws to me this error

[image]

Noted: I tried to put: `"proxy": "http://localhost:63762"` to package.json, still not working.

Comment: Call axios without await. Because your code ("await axios(config).catch(error => console.log(error))" ) apply for catch callback. Try without await